# ASP.NET Html.Partial and ViewBag

Tags: asp.net, razor

In my view I must load another cshtml. Path must be dynamic.

```
@Html.Partial("Programs/" + ViewBag.ProgramData.PrivateName + "/" + "Template")
```

But this was not work. My error "htmlhelper has no applicable method named partial dynamic"

Regards.

Comment: whats the value in the viewbag

Comment: Programs/dynamic/Template , how 3 part naming, first controller name then  paritial view name

Comment: Value is string. Finally I have for example "programs/video/template" in the view/shared folder

Comment: does it work in static naming

Comment: How to do dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Use Model instead of Viewbag. Pass partialviewname as model property from controller. I have tested this and worked perfectly

```
@Html.Partial("../Programs/" + Model.ViewName + "/" + "Template")
```

Comment: @ZiomekZKadwencji then it is something else, have you tested static naming, does it work

Comment: dd you get the answer?